# How to combat a disease taking over my Ficus Religiosa tree

Tags: diseases, ficus

I come from the tropical and temperate climate of Southeast Asia. I have a lovely Ficus Religiosa that sprouted in a small pot on my balcony naturally at about March this year. I transplanted it to a bigger pot using a rich potting soil mix shortly after, and the tree has grown much in the months ever since.

Recently, its come under attack from some disease which I cannot really identify. Attached here is a photo taken directly from my tree.

[image: necrotic leaf]

From my research, it looks like a sort of [leaf blotch disease](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237075355_Occurrence_of_leaf_blotch_disease_Botryosphaeria_Sp_in_Ficus_religiosa_in_Sri_Lanka), but the underlying pathogen might be different. Furthermore, the paper I've referenced doesn't seem to give much practical advice on a treatment plan. The treatement routine might be non-trivial, as it requires removing dead leaves to prevent spreading of the pathogen.

Help please!

Comment: This looks like fertilizer burn.  Too much fertilizer.  What was in the soil you used? Potting soil?  Tell us everything you did when you transplanted this plant and how long was it after you transplanted that you saw the beginning of this...leaf blotch.  Did you use potting soil from a bag?  How big is the pot to the size of your plant?  Did you put anything else in that pot besides sterilized potting soil and your plant?  How do you water?  Has this plant stayed in doors or is it out of doors or both?  I do not see a pathogen at all with this one picture!  Please send more?

Comment: https://www.jainsusa.com/images/6_Signs_of_overfertilizing_plants.jpg

Comment: Here are some more pictures: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1mlfm28WkfKR2gzTjN4MEpxNGM

Comment: there are these suspicious black nodules near the leaf stems, if you see the picture in my post there is also one in it...

Comment: The black thing looks like scale.  Could be the vector of virus which is another possibility with these yellow splotched leaves.  Please tell us more such as what fertilizer you used, what kind of soil (was it sterilized potting soil).  What do you mean by 'Rich Soil'?  How long has this condition been going on?  When was the last time it was green?  Do you have other house plants?  Have you put this plant out of doors within the last few months?  Do you smoke tobacco?  (Mosaic Virus).

Comment: Sorry that I can't recall some of the details as I never made any formal notes on some of the specifics. I use a combination of two chemical fertilizers that come in a beaded form - one is red while the other is blue. I think the soil used must have been potting soil, not fully sure if its sterilized. By rich I mean that the bag stated that its good for seedlings. The condition has been ongoing for about one month. It started off gently with only yellow specks on some leaves.

Comment: Right now when you go near the plant, you can also see some tiny white flies buzzing about, I wonder if they are related to mealy bugs...

Comment: Do you smoke or have friends that smoke?  Can you take a picture of the flies?  If they are white they are mostly...White Fly.  Grins.  This looks very much like a chemical burn.  The other pictures of mottled leaves looks like viral.  What happened anything at all with the transplanting and afterwards.  ANYTHING.  Have you looked under the leaves? With a magnifying glass? Gotta start ruling things out...this looks systemic to me.  Possibly fertilizer over dose.  Can you find the bag of soil you used?  The Fertilizer you used?  Need those ingredients.  Quickly.  Otherwise, I'd transplant asap.